# Spring boot 1.5.2.RELEASE accessing application.yml properties in static method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, groovy

I have a `Spring boot 1.5.2.RELEASE` app with below entries in my `application.yml`

```
digsig:
  trustweaver:      
    truststore: truststore.jks
    truststorePassword: xxxxxx
```

I am trying to access the above properties in a static class as below, code compiles but am getting a null in the logging as `caTrustStore = null`

```
public class CustomHttpsSSLConfig {

@Value("${digsig.trustweaver.truststore}")
private static  String caTrustStore;
 public static void init() {
  LOGGER.info("caTrustStore = "+caTrustStore);
 //method implementation
 }
}
```

I also tried accessing it in the main groovy class as below

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DigSigServiceApplication {

@Value("${digsig.trustweaver.truststore}") static String caTrustStore;

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LOGGER.info("caTrustStore caTrustStore = "+caTrustStore );      
    SpringApplication.run(DigSigServiceApplication.class, args);
}

}
```

but am getting below compilation error

```
Error:(15, 12) Groovyc: Apparent variable 'digsig' was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static field or class. Possible causes:
You attempted to reference a variable in the binding or an instance variable from a static context.
You misspelled a classname or statically imported field. Please check the spelling.
You attempted to use a method 'digsig' but left out brackets in a place not allowed by the grammar.
```

can someone help me with accessing `application.yml` properties?

Comment: your variable cannot be static

Comment: You can not use `"${...}"` with groovy, since those are used by groovy to replace in strings.  Use single quotes instead: `'${ ... }'`

Comment: If its a non static I can not access it in the static method, and I want the `CustomHttpsSSLConfig` to be initialized as static so that `SSLContext` is initialized with `truststore` and `keystore` for invoking the `Https` webservice. It works fine now but I have hardcoded the `keystore` and `truststore` values in the `CustomHttpsSSLConfig` but instead I want them to be configured in `application.yml`

Comment: @cfrick got rid of compilation errors with '${ ... }' but still am getting `caTrustStore caTrustStore = null` from the groovy class

Comment: You are asking for that value before spring fires up and does its magic.

Comment: Oops I totally overlooked the fact that `spring` kicks in after the `static` part, is there any other way to read those props from `application.yml` without spring

Comment: You can use SnakeYAML directly before spring starts up or if you only pulled spring for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can not use `"${...}"` for the spring variables, since Groovy itself uses this to replace in strings.  Use single quotes instead (`'${...}'`) so Groovy keeps them as they are.

Next don't use static vars for this and let spring do it's work before you ask the variable to be set.  Here is a complete, working example:

```
package x
@SpringBootApplication
@groovy.util.logging.Slf4j
class DigSigServiceApplication {

    @Value('${digsig.trustweaver.truststore}') 
    String caTrustStore;

    static void main(String[] args) {
        org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(DigSigServiceApplication, args)
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner init() {
        log.info("caTrustStore = $caTrustStore")
    }
}
```

Run with

```
digsig_trustweaver_truststore=XXX spring run spring.groovy
```

Output:

```
...
2017-04-24 17:21:59.125  INFO 14811 --- [       runner-0] x.DigSigServiceApplication               : caTrustStore = XXX
...
```